# Using Pandas to read XLSX file from Google Drive: "The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, pipedream

I'm trying to read a file downloaded from Google Drive using Pandas, in Python.
I'm running the code under Python 3.9, using Pipedream.

Using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

def handler(pipedream: "pipedream"):
    # Reference data from previous steps
    #print(pipedream.steps["trigger"]["context"]["id"])


    df = pd.read_excel('/tmp/file.xlsx', sheet_name='LIST_Client_2023-05-04-')

    # Return data for use in future steps
    return df
```

Using this file content
[image]

I'm getting this error which seems to be related to the data? but I'm not doing anything particular.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at your `worker.py` file in line 119 where the `ValueError` happens. What is the code that is used to create the `user_retval` "boolean" Based on the error I am guessing that `user_retval` is a `pandas.DataFrame` and not a boolean value. If you do `if pd.DataFrame(): print('Hello World')` it will result in the same error.

Comment: This is the code of the Pipedream platform, I don't have access to this. I've found a solution using Nodejs, but I hope a proper solution using Pandas will be found for others. https://pipedream.com/community/t/reading-a-google-sheet-xlxs-as-gsheet-file/6304

Comment: Without being able to go in and modify the `worker.py` file I do not think you will be able to prevent the error. You may need to report it as a bug to `pipedream` But I am also not familiar with `pipedream` so it is very possible I am way off base.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've reported the issue.